# Is there a built-in audio/video chat program in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, chat

I am looking for messenger/chat options within Windows 7.

Are there any built-in options?

Comment: We don't do software recommendations here at Superusr

Comment: "Are there any built-in options within windows 7?" how is this asking for a recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 does not have any built in chat programs, you would have to install a 3rd party chat program.

Ask for a recommendation at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't have it because Microsoft sell communicator and Lync. After they bought Skype there is one built in client but OS has to be Windows 8.1 or higher I think